# Can/Should Swift Class Function Return a completed UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift

Is it good practice to have a Swift class function that returns a completed UIView or UITableVIew?

I haven't seen any examples of that being done, but I assume that it is possible.

I'm looking for this to behave like a Javascript/Angular controller.

Desired:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func ReloadContent(sender: UIButton, type: Type) {
  if(type == "test"){
   self.tableView = BuildView().ReloadContent("test")
  } else {
   self.tableView = BuildView().ReloadContent("default")
  } 
}
```

Current (Not very reusable):

```
var sections = [[String:String]]()
var sectionRows = [[[String:String]]]()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func ReloadContent(sender: UIButton) {

  let path = "testcontent"
  let parameters = [
    "todo":"Token should come from somewhere.",
    "todo2":"There may be other parameters"
  ]

  // This loads the data into the table.
  populateTableData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 75, 320, 450);
  self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 
  return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
  return self.sectionRows[section].count
}

// This is what builds the cell for each row, and returns it.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

  // Collect the data for each
  let object = sectionRows[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // as NSDictionary

  cell.textLabel?.text = object["thingName"]
  return cell
}

// Select management
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
  println("Selected at \(indexPath.row)")
}

// Sets the height of the section header. Required to make the first section header appear.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return 50
}

// Sets the height of the section header. Required to make the first section header appear.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  return 25
}

// This creates a view for every row in the header.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

  var view = UIView()
  var listName = UILabel()
  var userName = UILabel()

  // Populate the data for the cell.
  listName.text = self.sections[section]["listname"]
  userName.text = self.sections[section]["userName"]

  listName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
  userName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

  let views = ["listName": listName, "view": view, "userName": userName ]
  view.addSubview(listName)
  view.addSubview(userName)


  var horizontallayoutContraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[listName]-10-|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
  view.addConstraints(horizontallayoutContraints)

  var verticalLayoutContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: listName, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  view.addConstraint(verticalLayoutContraint)


  // Returns the completed view.
  return view
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "completed"?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up @IanMacDonald. What I mean is that inside the viewDidLoad() function, a function could be called like this (rather than the seven tableView functions that currently build the view): 
myView = BuildViews().ViewMain()

Comment: Background is HTML/JS, recently Angular. I've been learning Swift in small pieces.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods are the only way to provide (or interact with) data in a `UITableView`. Why would you want to create a bloated "construct my view" method when compartmentalization makes maintenance easier and your code more readable?

Comment: Being a Swift/iOS newbie, I'm not sure what I'm asking either :)

Basically, what I think I want is for the data to populate a view inside one function, then have that function called by the view controller. 

That would allow any view controller to request this data table, rather than requiring every view that wants this table to build it uniquely for each view.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to have 2 different sets of data, 1 for test and 1 for normal usage. You may be better off creating a separate class which contains the data and creating it with the selected data set. Then, your UITableViewDataSource functions can call into it. Alternately, the other class can implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol and you can set the delegate to it when the table view is created.

Comment: Hold your datasource and delegate as an instance of a stand-alone object instead of using your `ViewController` as these things.